# cmake not including /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib

Tags: xcode

though I do

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
include_directories(/usr/local/opt/openssl/include)
link_directories(/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ssl crypto)
```

the `cmake` generated compiler command doesn't have `-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib` and linker is terminated by

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
```

the `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib` do has the `libssl.dylib`. Does `cmake` deliberately avoiding it in favour of Apples's `ssl` library?